# How many millions records can Mysql reasonably deal with with .NET?

Tags: .net, mysql

Anybody can tell his experience with MySQL and .NET dealing with millions of records ?

Would myself need to be able to cope with 50 to 100 Millions records and would like to hear about how you cope with this in your precise context so that I may inspire from it.

Comment: Are you referring to the total number of records in a database or in a single table?

Comment: Not sure, but the experts over on serverfault may be a better resource for this.

Comment: @tloach good idea will also ask on serverfault but I also need to ask here because it's also about .net coding.

Comment: Why do you mention .NET...are you planning on bringing 50 mill records back to the client? If so, no language will help you deal with that. Generally you filter all results coming back to the client in which case its a question of the DBMS. There are many large websites that use MySQL in production. http://royal.pingdom.com/royalfiles/0702_infrastructure_matrix.pdf

Comment: .net has specificities like DataReader etc. so indeed It's also a .net question.

Comment: The developer will have to make some simulation on these records.

Answer (score 3):

This question is fairly open ended...

If tuned right, mysql could deal with more than 100M records. It all depends on your indexing and table design, as well as proper server tuning and hardware.

Comment: The question is open ended because I have no idea yet :)

But for example you could give your own example about how you tuned it in your precise case.

Comment: You have to make sure you have the smallest possible datatype for each column, and index every column you plan to search on. Keep search results small, using the `LIMIT` and page through them. You should look on some mysql performance sites to see how to customize the config, it is different based on your hardware.